# Python pow() and modulus

Tags: python, pow

The pow() function in python3 provide the values for exponents.

```sh
>>>pow(2,3)
8
```

Python3 has support to negative exponents that is [image] can be represented using pow(10,-1). When I calculated pow(4,-1,5), it gave the output 4.

```sh
>>> pow(4, -1, 5)
4
```

I couldn't understand how the value 4 was calculated because, in the background, it performs
[image] and it didn't return a value 4 as a reminder when I calculated manually.

When -ve value is passed in two values it responds with the desired output as a manual method.

```sh
>>> pow(4, -1)
.25
```

What is the difference when calculating a negative exponent with a modulus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in python 3.8, the `pow` function allows you to calculate a modular inverse. As other answers have mentioned, this occurs when you use integers, have a negative exp, and base is relatively prime to mod. (this is the case in your example)

### What is a modular inverse?

Lets start with normal inverses. Some number `Y` has an inverse `X` such that `Y * X == 1`. Modular inverses are very similar. For some number `Y` and some modulus `mod`, there exists an inverse `X` such that `((X * Y) % mod) == 1`. From your example, you will see `(4 * 4) % 5` does in fact equal `1`, making 4 a valid modular inverse for `Y = 4` and `mod = 5`.

### How do you just get `pow(4, -1, 5) == 0.25`

Well, you could write it as separate steps `(4 ** -1) % 5`, but as the documentation says

> if mod is present, return base to the power exp, modulo mod (computed more efficiently than pow(base, exp) % mod)

So you may sacrifice performance by using `(4 ** -1) % 5`. Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to do with `pow`.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow);

> If *mod* is present and *exp* is negative, *base* must be relatively prime to *mod*. In that case, `pow(inv_base, -exp, mod)` is returned, where `inv_base` is an inverse to `base` modulo *mod*.